# How to create a custom settings control in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I would like to add a custom container to Leaflet. The container would contain edit controls and would be used as a kind of properties editor in order to customize the map (marker colors, zoom level, polyline color, etc ...). The panel would be displayed when the user clicks on a "settings" button located on the map.

Is there a Leaflet plugin for this?

I also had a look at how to implement [custom controls](http://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-3-controls.html), but I am really not clear how to achieve this. In particular it seems to me that I can only use JavaScript and DOM manipulations (and no direct HTML markup) in order to create a custom control.

Could someone please help me bootstrap the control? thanks!

**Edit**:

So I tried to create a very simple container consisting of a single checkbox "control" as follow:

```
L.Control.SettingsPanel = L.Control.extend({
  onAdd: function(map){
    var checkbox = L.DomUtil.create('input');
    checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkbox.style.width = '200px';
    return checkbox;
  }

});

L.control.settingsPanel = function(opts){
  return new L.Control.SettingsPanel(opts);
}
```

Comment: refer http://danielmontague.com/projects/easyButton.js/v1/examples/

Comment: Do you know https://github.com/turbo87/sidebar-v2/ ?

Comment: @Julien V this is exactly what I was looking for :) If you add your comment as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [sidebar v2](https://github.com/turbo87/sidebar-v2/) leaflet plugin might be what you are looking for.